Why (Get-ADDomainController).Name is different from $env:LOGONSERVER and also different from nltest /dsgetdc:myDOMAIN
Why does (Get-ADDomainController).Name returns a different result from $env:LOGONSERVER.Substring(2) ? :
PS C:\> (Get-ADDomainController).Name
PAR-DC02
PS C:\> $env:LOGONSERVER.Substring(2)
PAR-DC03
PS C:\> nltest /dsgetdc:$ENV:USERDNSDOMAIN | sls DC: | % { ( $_ -split('\s+|\.') )[2].substring(2) }
ANG-DC02

EDIT0 : Adding the -Discover option to Get-ADDomainController yields the same result :
PS C:\> (Get-ADDomainController -Discover).Name
PAR-DC02


I'm not 100% sure whether that's the correct usage of Get-ADDomainController. Its documentation says that you must pass the -Discover parameter to get the DC from Windows "DC Locator"; if you don't, then it seems to get just any DC available. I don't know for sure because I don't have that cmdlet available to test it myself.
Regardless, the LOGONSERVER environment variable is only set during logon and is the DC that handled your initial netlogon request; but because it's an environment variable, it never gets updated even if the system selects a different "best" DC later. The system is free to select a different preferred DC at any time, for any reason – even 15 minutes after logon, you may already be getting your Kerberos tickets from another DC.
(It's also a bit of an NT4-era relic from back when PDCs/BDCs existed – my understanding is that its only purpose was to allow logon scripts to get files from a DC via \\%LOGONSERVER%\foo, but now it's all redundant because you can get files from the DFS-replicated \\ad.example.com alias that Active Directory always has.)
